# Passing parameters to a function in switch case using dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

```
def doblue (): print "The sea is blue"
def dogreen (): print "Grass is green"
def doyellow (): print "Sand is yellow"

def redflag ():
    print "Red is the colour of fire"
    print "do NOT play with fire"

def errhandler ():
    print "Your input has not been recognised"
```

## set up a dictionary of actions

```
takeaction = {
"blue": doblue,
"green": dogreen,
"yellow": doyellow,
"red": redflag}

colour = raw_input("Please enter red blue green or yellow ")
takeaction.get(colour,errhandler)()
```

what if I have to pass some parameters to the doblue() or any function of that kind??

Comment: Please re-write your code using the code sample notation of StackOverflow to make it readable.

Comment: `takeaction.get(colour,errhandler)(parameters)` if this is what you want

Comment: @The6thSense: Is it possible to get an alphanumeric string in .get() and call the function based on the alphanumeric string??

Comment: could you be more clear /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `doblue` and other functions to receive arguments (optional or otherwise) like so

```
def doblue (item): print "The {} is blue".format(item)
```

Then you have the change your dispatch code to look like this

```
takeaction[colour](item).
```

This will pass `item` to your function.

On a more general point, your understanding of how dictionary dispatching works seems to be incomplete based your assumptions in this question. You need to revisit how it works before trying out stuff like this.

Comment: Is it possible to get an alphanumeric string in .get() and call the function based on the alphanumeric string??